# Convert an array of 'enum' to an array of 'int'

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to convert an Enum array to an int array:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
Item1,
Item2
}

int[] result = Array.ConvertAll<TestEnum, int>(enumArray, new Converter<TestEnum, int>(Convert.ToInt32));
```

For some reason Convert.ToInt32 doesn't work when used in Array.ConvertAll, so I had to make some changes:

```
int[] result = Array.ConvertAll<TestEnum, int>(enumArray, new Converter<TestEnum, int>(ConvertTestEnumToInt));

public static int ConvertTestEnumToInt(TestEnum te)
{
return (int)te;
}
```

Just out of curiosity, is there any way to have this working without using an extra method?

Regards

Comment: Your example `int[] result = Array.ConvertAll<TestEnum, int>(enumArray, new Converter<TestEnum, int>(Convert.ToInt32));` is really the same as `int[] result = Array.ConvertAll(enumArray, Convert.ToInt32);`. The overload of the `ToInt32` method in question takes in an `object` parameter. The delegate type (a constructed generic type `Converter<TestEnum, int>`) takes in a `TestEnum`. Now since `TestEnum` derives from `object`, you are surprised everything doesn't work. But this kind of magic (came in C# 2) is only allowed with _reference types_, and `TestEnum` is a _value type_.

Comment: Now, while Gravell's answer gives the best solution, your approach can be repaired by writing `int[] result = Array.ConvertAll(enumArray, x => Convert.ToInt32(x));`. In that case the lambda contains an invisible boxing from `TestEnum` to `object`. But as I said, Gravell's solution is more elegant and fast.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just cast using an anonymous method:

```
int[] result = Array.ConvertAll<TestEnum, int>(
    enumArray, delegate(TestEnum value) {return (int) value;});
```

or with C# 3.0, a lambda:

```
int[] result = Array.ConvertAll(enumArray, value => (int) value);
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it with int[] result = Array.ConvertAll(enumArray, value => (int) value);

Comment: Very nice!  Just used in code and works like a charm, nice to no have to individually convert the long list.  Thanks!

Comment: How about something as simple as `int[] res = (int[])(object)enumArray;`? See my answer. Of course, boxing included, but damn, I was so suprised. :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl actually that doesn't include any boxing; odd  - I'm pretty sure that didn't used to work, but I can't repro it failing on old frameworks

Comment: @MarcGravell what if I wanted to the opposite?

Comment: @Euridice either just cast it, or Enum.ToObject

Answer (score 63):

Luckily for us, C# 3.0 includes a `Cast` operation:

```
int[] result = enumArray.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

If you stop using arrays and start using `IEnumerable<>`, you can even get rid of the `ToArray()` call.

Comment: your answer makes no sense. what's `enumArray` ?

Comment: @BaltoStar enumArray is the array of enums that the OP references in his code.

Answer (score 16):

```cs
enumArray.Select(x => (int) x)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 7):

This worked like a charm:

```
var intArray = enumArray.Select(e => (int)e).ToArray();
```

as did this:

```
var intList = enumArray.Select(e => (int)e).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI: tested on .Net4ClientProfile and VS2010

Actually, you don't even need to use LINQ. You can just cast it in a normal way, provided that you drop the type down to `object`.

Having:

```
  enum One { one0, one1, one2, one3 };
  enum Two { two0, two1, two2, two3 };

  One[] vals = new One[] { One.one0, One.one3 };
```

we can play:

```
//Two[] aa = (Two[])vals; // impossible
  Two[] aa = (Two[])(object)vals; // possible!

  Two bb = aa[1]; // == Two.two3
```

At first, I was really suprised that the second line doesn't throw InvalidCast. But it does not.

Looking at the types explains things a little:

```
  bool check2 = bb.GetType().FullName == "Two";   // well, you'd guess that
  bool check3 = aa.GetType().FullName == "One[]"; // what?!
```

Seriously! The `aa` array is not `Two[]`. The array type has been "lost by variable" when it was cast to `object`, but both `vals` and `(object)vals` of course still refer to the same object. Then, after the following cast, it's still the `aa` object, the original array of `One[]`, just hidden behind a new variable type.

The `bb` object/variable has type of `Two` because the array's item read as an item of a `Two[]` array (along with the variable's types). The real array One[] is concealed by the `Two[]` type, so indexing the `Two[]` must result in value of `Two` type.

Furthermore, since the actual type is hidden and since Enum types seem to be treated lightly, let's check another thing:

```
  var numbers = (int[])(object)vals;
  var cc = numbers[0] + 10; // == 10, from one0's value
  var dd = numbers[1] + 10; // == 13, from one3's value
```

and similarly:

```
  bool check4 = numbers.GetType().FullName == "One[]"; // not System.Int32[]
```

So, as you might already guess, the other way around is possible too:

```
  var numbers2 = new int[]{ 0, 2, 99 };
  var enums = (One[])(object)numbers2;
  One ee = enums[0]; // == One.one0
  One ff = enums[1]; // == One.one2
  One gg = enums[2]; // == ((One)99)
```

and int[] also remembers its real type, even if casted to `One[]`:

```
  bool check5 = numbers2.GetType().FullName == "System.Int32[]";
```

Even further, you cannot trust the `as` and `is` operators when the array is passed as `object`:

```
  bool really_true1 = vals is One[];
  bool really_true2 = vals is Two[];
  bool really_true3 = vals is System.LoaderOptimization[];
```

This one was a 'gotha!' for me recently.

It actually **reuses** the original array object (instead of duplicating it like with LINQ) and it exposes it as different type - be it Two[] or int[]. It's seems to be a "true cast", no boxing. Much different than LINQ-driven copying&conversion.

Comment: btw: as always, JS already wrote about that (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15168879/717732) and his words somewhat suggest that there is no extra boxing "as the CLR knows there's no difference".

Comment: this isn't boxing; you can't "box" an array, since an array is always a reference type; very interesting

Comment: Thanks for the note, I don't know why I didn't thought in these terms, and looking at it like that it's obvious. I've corrected the bits in the text.

Comment: @MarcGravell: are you sure there's no boxing..? Maybe arrays are somewhat special in these terms? I've checked a few things, and for example: `var x = (object[])(object)(new List<int>[5])` ia valid cast, but `(object[])(object)(new int[5])` is not a valid cast, and `(object[])(object)(new One[5])` is not valid too, whereas `(object[])(object)(new System.Enum[5])` is valid. Maybe I forgot about something again, but it seems like the whole array is either being 'value array' or 'ref array'. Note that's a difference between `int/One` and `Enum`, latter treated as 'ref/object', former - value.

Comment: @MarcGravell is right, it is not boxing. In the example `(int[])(object)(new One[5])` we are "mis-using" the fact that the runtime considers types `int[]` and `One[]` assignable from each other, in some sense. C# doesn't agree with the runtime's concept of assignability in this case. In the example `(object[])(object)(new System.Enum[5])` we are simply using the **array covariance** which works only with classes (that is _reference types_). Remember that `System.Enum` is a `class`, a reference type`, the base class of your `One` type.

Comment: Nah.. it's no sense i nany boxing.. `(new int[5]).GetType().IsValueType` of course is false.. still, cast to object[] fails, suprise again.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: thanks. I tend to fail to notice that C# and CLR has different specs in some nuances. This is clearly one of them, since I force the compiler to delegate the casts and typechecks to the runtime. I've seen quite similar things during some inter-ops (COM probably, I don't remember) or different .Net languages, where the flexibility of some CLR rules are much more visible.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Another example, related, is `uint[] myUnsignedArray = (uint[])(Array)(new[] { -2, -4, -6, });`. The runtime allows to treat a reference to a `System.Int32[]` object as a `System.UInt32[]` reference. Of course `myUnsignedArray.GetType()` will get the real type. But this is a violation of the C# spec according to which no reference conversion between `int[]` and `uint[]` shall exist. Which is why we have to put in the intermediate cast to `object` or `Array` or something, to satisfy the C# compiler.

Answer (score 2):

`int[] b = Array.ConvertAll((int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestEnum)), Convert.ToInt32);`