# Casting an array of integers to an array of enums

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have an enum that has 4 values:

```
public enum DriveRates 
{ 
    driveSidereal = 0,
    driveLunar = 1, 
    driveSolar = 2, 
    driveKing = 3 
}
```

I have an array of values that I want to cast to an array of DriveRates. However when I do `var rates = (DriveRates[])ret;`, with `ret` being an object array of numbers (probably integers), it says `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'ASCOM.DeviceInterface.DriveRates[]'.`

`ret`=`{0,1,2,3}`. How should I do this instead. Again, I am trying to convert an array of enum values to an array of enum...well, values :) But I'm trying to convert from type `object[]` to type `DriveRates[]`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't just cast the array, if it's really an `object[]`. You *can* create a new array pretty easily though:

```
var enumArray = originalArray.Cast<DriveRates>().ToArray();
```

If it were *actually* an `int[]` array to start with, you could cast - although you'd have to talk nicely to the C# compiler first:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    enum Foo
    {
        Bar = 1,
        Baz = 2
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        Foo[] foos = (Foo[]) (object) ints;
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

The C# compiler doesn't believe that there's a conversion from `int[]` to `Foo[]` (and there isn't, within the rules of C#)... but the CLR is fine with this conversion, so as long as you can persuade the C# compiler to play along (by casting to `object` first) it's fine.

This *doesn't* work when the original array is really an `object[]` though.

Comment: Hmm...Yes, it's an array of objects. Apparently an array of objects can't be converted to an array of ints.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler: Well it can be converted to a *new* array - but the *existing* array can't be just treated as an array of ints, as they have different representations.

Comment: It's worth noticing, that even `is` and `as` operators may get confused with types of enum arrays, see the last snippet at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21186137/717732 - all three checks say 'true', while `.GetType()` of course says not.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.  There is no way to cast between an array of reference types and an array of value types.  You will need to manually copy the elements into the new array

```
DriveRates[] Convert(object[] source) { 
  var dest = new DriveRates[source.Length];
  for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) { 
    dest[i] = (DriveRates)source[i];
  }
  return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...or with linq, especially if you need to do some extra things with every element in one line:

```
DriveRates[] enumArray = originalArray.Select(o => (DriveRates)o).ToArray();
```